# Image Scroll in Indoor Positioning System - Android

Tags: java, android, indoor-positioning-system

I am working in Indoor Positioning System .. It will be an android app like [this](http://thenextweb.com/eu/2010/12/22/gecko-could-kickstart-an-indoor-positioning-mobile-app-explosion/)
I am trying to make custom View for displaying the map, First step I make a Scrollable ImageView following article called 'A simple implementation of a scrollable ImageView'

The problem is when I put a marker in the map (using another ImageView for marker), When I start scrolling .. the markers start disappearing like [this](http://postimg.org/image/i5ulsikjr/)

So can any one help me ? I want markers to stick into the map and only the map scroll (I mean like Google Maps)

Comment: Post a relevant code fragment. Show us how you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: Dear @Esraa, did you please to share some information how to create and display indoor map in Android? Which tool you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating map, Canvas is a better option, in canvas you can implement scroll,zoom,rotation etc.
In canvas it supports any number of bitmaps, and also we can draw programmatically within the canvas.

Comment: `Ciril`  Could you please provide some useful links or something else which helps to implement indoor navigation?

Comment: Thanks for your response :), Yup I will start using Canavs, but I need a help to know from where should I start, and I think sample of code will be good for me to understand .. If you can guide me, I will be thankful :)

Comment: _@Esraa_, _Alex_ [Try this](http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/8/) for canvas zoom and translate